# PHP test for an empty form element doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I have two elements on my form - textarea and file element for file uploads.
I need one of the two not to be empty in order for the form to get submitted.
Here is how I check it:

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['text'];
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['uploadedfile'];    
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if((empty($_POST['text'])) && (empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']))) {
                $errors .= 'Please either enter your text or attach a file.<br/><br/>';
            }

        }
if (!$errors) { do some code...
              header("Location: http://mysite.com/mysite/submitted.html");
} 
else {
            echo '<div style="color: red; font-weight: bold; text-align: center"> The form was not sent. Some data is missing:<br />' . $errors . '<br/>
                    </div>';



        }
    }

?>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <form id="form" action="quot_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="text"><?php echo $text?></textarea>
        </p>
        <p class = "upload">        
            <input type="file" class="file" name="uploadedfile" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

Any idea why the form gets submitted even with both fields empty and no error message gets echoed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a logical AND (&&) instead of a logical OR (||).

```
if((empty($_POST['text'])) || (empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])))
```

---

Added:  Looks like the files array is problematic to check in this manner.  Try this:

```
if((empty($_POST['text'])) && ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] < 1))
```

Comment: The if is about the error, not the correct behaviour. The error is when both are empty so AND is the correct operator.

Comment: Whoops.  Well, one of them is clearly returning false.  Mostly likely the textarea has some cruft (empty spaces) in it.

Comment: Or not, based on how the $_FILES array works.  See updated answer.

Comment: That's part of it, but it wouldn't explain the case where both are empty and it still fails.

Comment: @Sylverdrag - Because the $_FILES array isn't ever empty() per se.

Comment: John Green - PageSpike, your update worked!
Thank you!
Actually my code was working fine last night. After that I've done a number of CSS/HTML formatting and don't know at what point the PHP stopped working. I tried to go back, but just lost track.
Thank you a million!

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it as follows

```
$test = $_POST['test'];
if(empty($test, $uploadfile) {
//Do Something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The link at the bottom explains much better but the jest of it is:

empty() cannot be used with string variables for the simple fact that empty() returns true if your variable is set the the string value '0'. If the string character '0' is a possibly valid value for your string variable — if all non-zero-length strings are valid — you cannot use empty(). This is even more dangerous if you are using empty() to check if a string variable is defined. Also worth mentioning, empty() returns false for a string value that is nothing but a single space (or any number of spaces really).

you cannot simply replace the use of empty() with a conditional that checks if the string variable is equal to null or has a string length of zero. If your string variable happens to be undefined, empty() will quietly return true whereas strlen($mystring) and $mystring == null will throw PHP warnings. If your variable may possibly be undefined, then you have to first check of the variable is defined using isset(). After that you can check if the string is null.

Answer can be found here:
http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/09/careful-with-php-empty.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always use this as the tester `if (empty($_POST["text"]) ^ empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']))`  It use an xor, which tests if either is set to true, but not both, or neither.